# Rails Form "Must exist" Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created this form, using [simple form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), for a post class of a forum:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :title, label: false, placeholder: 'Title', required: true %>
  <%= p.input :description, as: :text, label: false, placeholder: 'Describe your post', required: true %>
  <%= p.association :category, label: false, required: true,
  collection: Category.order(:title), prompt: 'Choose category' %>
  <%= p.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now I go to the page and try to create a post and I get this:

[Image for Form Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUQRT.png)

I have no idea how to proceed since this objects (C, C++, etc) all exist. Here is where they were created, in `seeds.rb`

```
c1 = Category.create(title: "C++", image_url: 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/c--logo-icon-0.png')
c2 = Category.create(title: "Rails", image_url: 'http://perfectial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ruby.png')
c3 = Category.create(title: "Python", image_url: 'http://python.net/~goodger/projects/graphics/python/newlogo-repro.png')
c4 = Category.create(title: "Cobol", image_url: 'http://insights.dice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cobol.png')
c5 = Category.create(title: "C", image_url: 'https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/28449/screenshots/1040285/cap-logo-ideas3.png')
c6 = Category.create(title: "Perl", image_url: 'http://news.perlfoundation.org/onion_logo.png')
```

And yes, I did run rake db:seed and restarted the server before trying it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has very little to do with the language level object model and is framework/orm specific. `belongs_to` associations in Rails 5 default to being non optional.

So if you for example have this setup:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category
  has_many :posts
end
```

You will get a validation error if `post.category_id` is nil.This can happen example if you have forgotten to whitelist the `category_id` attribute.

```
def post_attributes
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :category_id)
end
```

Additionally you can declare the `category` association as optional:

```
class Post
  # this was the default behavior in Rails 4
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `def post_attributes`?

Comment: Yes, doing a little to much multitasking :)

Comment: Additionally you should use `.create!` in your `seeds.rb` - it will raise an error if the validation does not pass instead of silently failing.

Comment: Well the "Must exist" problem stopped, get your correct answer :) but now I click create post and for some reason it is giving rollback transaction :/

Comment: Do you have any uniqueness validations that might be failing?

Comment: No, there is no uniqueness usage in post creation at all

Comment: Try writing '@post.errors.inspect' to the log or using abort or byebug or some other debugging step.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!